# the smallest normal extension of separable extension is separable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $E$ be finite separable extension of a field $k$. Let $K$ be the smallest normal extension of $k$ containing $E$. Does $K$ be separable?

Actually this is from the statements of Lang's the algebra, Corollary 1.6 at p.263., to show that $K$ is Galois extension. Lang states it obvious since $K$ is finite composite of finite number of conjugates of elements in $E$.

I showed that $K$ is such components, using Lang's remark on separable extension. But still have no idea to see $K$ is separable. By Lang's notation, $K = (\sigma_{1}E)(\sigma_{2}E)\cdots(\sigma_{n}E)$ where $n = [E:k]$, $\{ \sigma_{i} \}_{i=1}^{n}$ is embeddings $E \to k^{a}$, a algebraic closure of $k$ over $k$. Could you give me some hint for the reason why each $(\sigma_{i}E)$ is separable over $k$?

Comment: In fact, $K$ is obtained by adjoining to $E$ the roots of all minimal polynomials over $k$ of elements from $E$. Can you see now why is it separable?

Comment: @user26857 What if some irreducible polynomial of an element $\alpha \in E$ is $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)^n$?

Comment: It seems you forgot that $k\subset E$ is separable.

Comment: @user26857 In Lang's definition, element is separable if which extension is separable, which implies that its degree is the same as separable degree. But polynomial is separable if it has no multiplicity other than 1. Does it mean that if element is separable than polynomial is separable?

Comment: Yes, an element is separable iff its minimal polynomial has no multiple roots.

Comment: See also [here](https://books.google.ro/books?id=baEQAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA373&lpg=PA373&dq=separable+off+the+minimal+polynomial+has+no+multiple+roots&source=bl&ots=JaKDRrqTMO&sig=CN9ELNsm6lGQMPBBcLEErnS0PCM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwA2oVChMI8LrFvq-UyAIVQ7UUCh0S4QZ-#v=onepage&q&f=false), Definition 8.5.2.

Comment: @user26857 Could you please show me how to prove that K is the adjunction to E of the roots of all mininal polynomials over k of some elements in E?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition.** Let $E \supset k$ be an algebraic extension. Fix an algebraic closure $k^a$ of $k$ containing $E$.

- The *separable degree* $[E:k]_s$ is the cardinality of the set of embeddings of $E$ into $k^a$ over $k$, that is,
  $$
  [E:k]_s = \#\{ \sigma \colon E \to k^a \mid \sigma \text{ is a field homomorphism and } \sigma|_k = \operatorname{id} \}.
  $$
- $\alpha \in E$ is *separable* over $k$ if $[k(\alpha):k]_s = [k(\alpha):k]$.
- A polynomial $f \in k[X]$ is *separable* if it has no multiple roots in $k^a$.

**Theorem.**
Let $E \supset k$ be an algebraic extension. Then, the following are equivalent:

1. $[F:k]_s = [F:k]$ for every subfield $F$
   of $E$ such that $F \supset k$ and $F$ is finitely generated over $k$.
2. Every element $\alpha$ of $E$ is separable over $k$.
3. For every $\alpha \in E$, the irreducible polynomial $\operatorname{Irr}(\alpha,k,X)$ is separable.
4. There exists a set of generators $\{ \alpha_i \}_{i \in I}$ of $E$ over $k$
   such that each $\alpha_i$ is separable over $k$.

**Definition.** If an algebraic extension $E/k$ satisfies any of the above equivalent conditions, then we say that $E/k$ is a *separable extension*.

---

Now, suppose that $E/k$ is a finite separable extension. Let $\sigma \colon E \to k^a$ be an embedding of $E$ over $k$. To show that $\sigma(E)$ is a separable extension of $k$, we will show equivalently that the irreducible polynomial of each element of $\sigma E$ is separable.

So, let $\alpha \in E$ and let $f(X) = \operatorname{Irr}(\alpha,k,X)$ be its irreducible polynomial. Since $E$ is separable over $k$, $f(X)$ is separable. Since $\sigma$ is an embedding over $k$, $\sigma(f) = f$. Since an embedding maps a root of $f$ to a root of $\sigma(f)$, $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a root of $\sigma(f) = f$. Since $f(X)$ is irreducible over $k$, $f(X)$ is the irreducible polynomial of $\sigma(\alpha)$ as well.

Hence, the irreducible polynomial of $\sigma(\alpha)$ is separable. Since $\sigma(\alpha)$ is an arbitrary element of $\sigma(E)$, every element of $\sigma(E)$ is separable over $k$ and hence, $\sigma(E)$ is separable over $k$.